# How am I able to seed if I have no ports forwarded in my torrent client?

Tags: bittorrent

Title is pretty self-explanatory. Often times when I am downloading torrents, even though I have no ports forwarded (uPnP disabled as well), I am able to still upload a lot of data to other clients. Why is this the case? I thought in order for other people to download from me, I need to have my ports forwarded?

Comment: You need to have open ports. Perhaps your router or ISP is opening ports instead of blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to forward ports for *incoming* connections. However you can make *outgoing* connections without issue. Once your torrent establishes an outgoing connection, data can be transmitted between seeders and peers.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a connection is established it's always a two way.. you upload as well as you download.You dont need to forward ports in case you're using a LAN connection but if you're on a Wi-Fi network then you have to in order to host a torrent by yourself but you can limit the amount of data you upload on torrent by setting the limit

NOTE: if you limit the upload to less than 20kbps then your download speed also decreases